# I have 30 GB index size then what should be the suitable plan with solrcloud

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

I have 30 GB index size then what should be the suitable plan with solrcloud. How many shards and replication factors should be used and how many nodes on each shard. 
there are few other concerns if some one could help

1. if I am updating delta on a single shard but two different nodes would it be problematic updating nodes at the same time with two different entities.
2. what is best time for rescheduling in solr when we have 500 document per minute.

Thanx a million.

Comment: Even this article does not fit exactly your problem, I suppose you should read it: http://lucidworks.com/blog/2012/07/23/sizing-hardware-in-the-abstract-why-we-dont-have-a-definitive-answer/

Comment: I don't think anyone can give you an exact answer based on the information you have given. You would need to do performance testing based on the expected write/read load on your cluster to draw any conclusions. Index size is important, but the types of queries and the tokenization/filtering during the querying/indexing phases also plays a part.